# Do you nou how to run xmlrpc requests from node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, xml-rpc

I wonder what is the best way to use xmlrpc with node.js, there is a npm plugin but I can't find how to use it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A piece of code from a working project:

```
const xmlrpc = require('xmlrpc');

const client = xmlrpc.createSecureClient({
    host: 'yourhost'
    port: 'yourport'
    path: '/somepath'
});

function fetchData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xmlData = {
            table: 'GroupAssign',
            limit: 1000,
            page : 0,
        };

        return client.methodCall('DataService.query', [
            xmlData.table,
            xmlData.limit,
            xmlData.page,
        ], (error, data) => {
            if (error) { return reject(error); }
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

So you need to

1. require `xmlrpc`
2. create a client
3. invoke `methodCall` with a method name as the first param

Comment: This is so easy to understand, thank you so much!

Comment: @Anton i tried this but i get result: undefined. Can u help me to fix?